# How to update Javascript Global Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, global-variables, javascript-objects

I'm not able to access the updated global array (`a1`), it shows an empty array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var video_object = { title1:"", desc:"", link1:"",url1:""};
 var a1 = [];

 alert(a1.toSource()); // Inital array Value
$(function() {

    $("#upload1").click(function(){

        video_object.title1 = $("#title1").val();       
        video_object.desc = $("#desc1").val();                  
        video_object.link1 = $("#extra1").val();    
        video_object.url1  = $("#path1").val();     
        a1.push(video_object);

        alert(a1.toSource()); // Array Value updated initially (but gets null value afterwards)
    }); });


</script>
```

Comment: So, what seems to be the problem here?  You just gave us a block of code, care to describe it and the issue you are having?

Comment: @RocketHazmat : I'm not able to access the updated global array, it shows the null array. please help.

Comment: Where does it show "the null array"? When?

Comment: Where are you trying to access this array?  What do you mean "null array"?  Do just mean the array is empty?

Comment: yes, the array is empty.

Comment: Where does `toSource` come from?

Comment: @Quentin: From here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource  P.S. It only works in Firefox

Comment: You are adding the same object `video_object` to `a1` array every time `$("#upload1")` is clicked. This likely is not you want.

Comment: @JimBrutan: Not sure if this is the source of your problems, but if you are calling `a1.push(video_object);` more than once, then you will be pushing the *same* object into the array each time.

Comment: It should just have lots of references to the same object then, nothing should be `null`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: if i access this Global Array in another event, I get a empty array. for example -> $("#update2").click(){alert(a1.toSource());});  // The alert displays an empty array

Comment: @JimBrutan — That shouldn't happen. You need to provide a complete reduced test case that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JimBrutan: Did you click on `#upload1` *before* clicking on `#update2`?

Comment: Ah. I think I know what is going on, but would need to see the HTML to tell if my speculation is right. You really should provide a proper test case.

Comment: what are the clicked elements? are they submitting the form, so the page gets reloaded all the time?

Comment: @Igor: Oh yes, my button was inside the form. now my problem is fixed. Thank you #ignor and all other to help me overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like function Object.prototype.toSource() supports  only in Firefox.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: The question says that the array is null, not that it throws an error because `toSource` is undefined. While this is a problem with the code, it is not the problem the question is asking about.

Comment: @Quentin time to close the question as no-repro/too-localised, then?

Comment: You linked the Russian version. Better remove the language from the link, so that people will see the page in their language.

Comment: @JanDvorak — More of an "unclear what is being asked" I think

Comment: I changed link to MDN

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Compass Thanks for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a1 = [];

  alert(a1.toSource()); // Inital array Value
  $(function() {

    $("#upload1").click(function(){
      var video_object = { title1:"", desc:"", link1:"",url1:""};

      video_object.title1 = $("#title1").val();     
      video_object.desc = $("#desc1").val();                    
      video_object.link1 = $("#extra1").val();  
      video_object.url1  = $("#path1").val();       
      a1.push(video_object);

      alert(a1.toSource());
    });
  });
</script>
```